# Why MongoDB has justOne option for update command? Or does it?

Tags: mongodb

I can see this is the syntax for the update command in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#definition):

> ```
> db.collection.update(
>    <query>,
>    <update>,
>    {
>      upsert: <boolean>,
>      multi: <boolean>,
>      writeConcern: <document>,
>      collation: <document>,
>      arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
>    }
> )
> ```

I do not see `justOne` option here. And it also says:

> By default, the update() method updates a single document

And on the [same page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#sharded-collections), it also says:

> All `update()` operations for a sharded collection that specify the
>   `justOne` option must include the shard key or the `_id` field in the
>   query specification. `update()` operations specifying `justOne` in a
>   sharded collection which do not contain either the shard key or the
>   `_id` field return an error.

And when I tested this in a sharded cluster, I can see the below query:

```
db.people.explain().update({},{$set : {age : 25}})
```

returns the below error message:

> A single update on a sharded collection must contain an exact match on
>   _id (and have the collection default collation) or contain the shard key (and have the simple collation). Update request: `{ q: {}, u: {
>   $set: { age: 25.0 } }, multi: false, upsert: false }`, shard key
>   pattern: `{ name: 1.0 }`

So I don't see any usage or need of `justOne` option in `update` command. Why does the documentation say this option is available for update command? What does it mean?

Comment: Good question, I can only assume that the `justOne` option here is the `multi: false` case (which is the default). Weird that they seem to have invented a "virtual" option in the docs.